# Change the taskbar color of Windows 10

Tags: c#, winapi, user32, dwm

Is it possible to change the color of the taskbar programmatically? I want to change the color to solid (opaque) black but ONLY for the taskbar (That's the reason why I can't use the `DwmSetColorizationParameters` function. It changes the color for entire UI of Windows)

I am able to disable the transparency by finding the taskbar's `hWnd` (`FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);`) and setting the transparency by DWM API function `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` but I don't know how to change the color.

Comment: Doesn't the user get to decide?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. The taskbar window doesn't have its own special color.

DWM sets the color for all windows, that's why you can modify it with the DWM APIs (albeit an undocumented, unsupported one). The taskbar is just a window. Nothing special.

Indeed, you can hack around with things like `FindWindow`, but even putting aside the concerns about how inherently fragile that type of thing is, there's still no way to set a different glass color for an individual window.

Maybe you could look into creating your own theme? (Also officially unsupported.)

Comment: I've found a [tool](http://www.windows10insider.com/2015/12/make-taskbar-transparent-in-Windows-10.html) that can also change the color of the taskbar (only this color) but this tool has also other unwanted functionality. That's the reason I think it's possible but I don't know yet how to achieve.

Comment: Well, [the source code is available](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/files/Version%203.6.8%20%28final%20open-source%20release%29/) for Classic Shell. The latest version is not open source, that's an older version, but it should still be enough to see how they're doing it. It's almost guaranteed to be an ugly hack. Can't recommend strongly enough *against* doing that. This is the kind of stuff that causes Windows Update to brick your system.

Comment: This answer is now a bit dated as Windows 10 finally allows custom themes including the Task Bar color.  I only state this as this (once correct) answer is no longer correct.  Unfortunately at time of writing this, documentation is very sparse, so I do not have a better answer to provide.